# java 8 Consumer won't override a value

Tags: java, java-8

```
private String a;
private Boolean bBoolean = false;

private String tmp(Boolean aBoolean, Boolean bBoolean, Consumer<Boolean> consumer){
    if (aBoolean == null) {
            return "-";
    }
    consumer.accept(aBoolean); // do bBoolean = aBoolean;
    return bBoolean ? "yes" : "no";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();

    main.a = main.tmp(true, main.bBoolean, c -> main.bBoolean = c);
    System.out.println(main.a);
    System.out.println(main.bBoolean);
}
```

For `main.bBoolean` the output is `true` and for `main.a` it's `no`.

How is it possible?

Comment: Please remove all the unnecessary code so you get the minimum working example, from which you will easily see what you are doing. There are many things which do not have any influence on your output. Mixing static calls and non-static calls in the same class is also confusing. As well as declaring the variables as `Boolean` if you never put there anything else than `true` or `false`. Maybe it has some meaning in your program somewhere else but here on StackOverflow it's much better if you remove all the fluff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing a copy of `main.bBoolean` to `tmp`, when its value is still `false`.

`consumer.accept(aBoolean);` assigned `true` to `this.bBoolean` (since `aBoolean` is `true`), but the local variable `bBoolean` remains `false`. Hence "no" is returned by the `tmp` method.

If you change:

```
return bBoolean ? "yes" : "no";
```

to:

```
return this.bBoolean ? "yes" : "no";
```

you'll get "yes", which means calling the `accept` method of the `Consumer<Boolean>` did change the value of the instance variable `main.bBoolean`.

Answer (score 0):

I try to keep the param names of my methods different from the actual fields, except for the constructor.

If this is not the case then extra care must be taken to make sure that the use of the local params is not confused with the actual fields

```
private String tmp(Boolean aParam, Boolean bParam, Consumer<Boolean> consumer){
    if (aParam == null) {
            return "-";
    }
    consumer.accept(aParam); // do bBoolean = aBoolean;
    //check the instance field and not the param
    return bBoolean ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

This is easier to reason and read than the original one.
The intent is clear and in case issues, easier to debug as well!!!!